# MSSQL server replication - compatibility level

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, compatibility, merge-replication

I currently have two SQL servers in a merge replication setup. The publisher is running SQL Server 2016 Standard and the subscriber is running SQL Server 2016 Express. For some reason i am not able to change the compatibility of the publication in the publication properties. The only one listed there is "SQL Server 2008 or later". Likewise i get the error:

"Incorrect value for parameter '@publication_compatibility_level'"

When running this T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @publication AS sysname;  
SET @publication = N'publication name*' ;   
EXEC sp_changemergepublication   
    @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1,
    @publication = @publication, 
    @property = N'publication_compatibility_level', 
    @value = N'130RTM'
GO
```

The only allowed value is "100RTM" corresponding with the only version i can pick in the publication properties.

I would like to change the compatibility version to 2016. Any indications as to why this is not possible or how it can be achieved is much appreciated.

Comment: Simply put: because it isn't necessary -- SQL Server 2016 *is* "2008 or later", and there are no versions beyond "100RTM", as is [clearly documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-changemergepublication-transact-sql). Why do you even think it's necessary to change it?

Comment: Thank you for the response!
I did browse that doc, but was confused by articles like [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152523(v=sql.110).aspx), which illustrates it with @value = N'110RTM'.
I didn't think it was necessary, however i was under the impression it could improve performance of the replication.

Comment: The doc you linked to is wrong. I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/pull/197) to have it fixed.